# MYSQL how to map these join results?

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

```
Objects
ID | Name
----------
1    name1

Tags
ID | ObjectId | Tag
--------------------
1    1          tag1
2    1          tag2

Attributes
ID | ObjectId | Key | Value
--------------------
1    1          key1  value1  
2    1          key2  value2
```

I'd like to retrieve these values and map them into a single object in my application code. Something like this:

```
id: 1,
name: name1,
tags: [tag=tag1, tag=tag2],
attributes: [{key=key1, value=value1}, {key=key2, value=value2}]
```

However, this join query doesn't work quite how I expected:

```
SELECT      o.id, o.name, t.tag, a.key, a.value 
FROM        objects o 
LEFT JOIN   attributes a on a.ObjectId = o.id
LEFT JOIN   tags t on t.ObjectId = o.id
WHERE       o.id = 1
```

It gives me these 4 results:

```
1 | key1 | value1 | tag1
1 | key2 | value2 | tag1
1 | key1 | value1 | tag2
1 | key2 | value2 | tag2
```

This is surprising to me because I would expect `null` for half the `Attribute` and half the `Tags` results.

When I map this in application code, I end up with duplicate values because I have no way of knowing if things like `tag1` should occur multiple times.

How should I query this data such that I can map into an objet like this in application code?

Comment: @Barmar should be `o.id`, updated

Comment: You don't get any nulls because both tables are just joining with `objects`, and it has matching rows in both child tables. Then it creates a cross-product between all those matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want using `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Use the `DISTINCT` modifier to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT o.id, o.name, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag) AS tags, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a.key, '=', a.value)) AS attributes
FROM object AS o
LEFT JOIN   attributes a on a.ObjectId = o.id
LEFT JOIN   tags t on t.ObjectId = o.id
WHERE       o.id = 1
```

You can then split up these comma-separated and equal-separated strings in the application language.

Or you can use your existing query, and merge the related rows in the application language.

If you need the result to contain duplicates if there are duplicates in the input tables, join with subqueries that use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT o.id, o.name, t.tags, a.attributes
FROM object AS o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ObjectId, GROUP_CONCAT(key, '-', value) AS attributes
    FROM attributes
    GROUP BY ObjectId
) AS a ON a.ObjectId = o.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ObjectId, GROUP_CONCAT(tag) AS tags
    FROM tags
    GROUP BY OBjectId
) AS t ON a.ObjectId = t.id
WHERE o.id = 1
```

Comment: I'm concerned about the `Distinct` modifier. Will it impact query performance? And will it remove legitimate duplicates? (the value `tag1` can be reused)

Comment: So if there are two rows in tags with `ObjectId = 1, tag = tag1`, you want the result to contain `tag1,tag1`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do the grouping without losing legitimate duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8 and up has native JSON support, so you can do this:

```
SELECT      o.ID, o.Name, t.tags, a.attributes
FROM        Objects o
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT ObjectId, JSON_ARRAYAGG(Tag) tags FROM Tags GROUP BY ObjectId) t
            ON t.ObjectId = o.ID
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT ObjectId, JSON_OBJECTAGG(`Key`, `Value`) attributes FROM Attributes GROUP BY ObjectId) a
            ON a.ObjectId = o.ID
WHERE       o.ID = 1;
```

which results in

```
| ID  | Name  | tags             | attributes                           |
| --- | ----- | ---------------- | ------------------------------------ |
| 1   | name1 | ["tag1", "tag2"] | {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"} |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/etzEgPZ3hqxewsxkfrtb7b/1)